# Java connecting to sql server

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, database-connection

I have this code:

```
try
    {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://myMachine:1433/myDB;instance=sql2008;user=myUserName;password=myPassword;"
        );

        System.out.println("connected");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is the exception I get:

```
Unable to get information from SQL Server: myMachine.
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.MSSqlServerInfo.<init>(MSSqlServerInfo.java:97)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.<init>(ConnectionJDBC2.java:276)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3.<init>(ConnectionJDBC3.java:50)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)
        at Library.MusicItem.Save(MusicItem.java:22)
        at AddMusicForm.jButton1ActionPerformed(AddMusicForm.java:86)
        at AddMusicForm.access$000(AddMusicForm.java:17)
        at AddMusicForm$1.actionPerformed(AddMusicForm.java:45)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6289)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6054)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4652)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4482)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4482)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:644)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:603)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:601)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:617)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:615)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:614)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

In Sql Configuration Manager I have set TCP/IP, Named Pipes, Shared memory and VIA set to enabled.

I've verified that the provided username and password are correct. Also the port number is correct.

Why do I get this error and how to solve this?

PS: I am using sql server 2008 express

Comment: Is the database up and running on port 1433? If you go to the command line, if you do `ping myMachine`, what do you get (does it resolve to an IP? That is, does myMachine resolve to an IP address that you can reach from where you are running the test? If you do `netstat -an` from the command line, do you see a TCP or UDP entry for `myMachine:1433`? That is, SqlServer is binding to that hostname and port (and not, say, to localhost or 127.0.0.1)? If indeed it's running where you can reach it, can you connect with that username and pwd from SqlServer Config Manager?

Comment: If i do netstat -an, I don't see anything with a port number of 1433. When I ping my machine I get this: `Reply from fe80::807e:73b6:47fb:9348%11: time<1ms`. I can login with the username using the config manager.

Comment: @Martjin, what do you get from `ping myMachine`?

Comment: Then I get `Reply from fe80::807e:73b6:47fb:9348%11: time<1ms`

Comment: Did you do the steps in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277/en-us?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've got it. The `SQL Service browser` service wasn't started. After I started this service, I could connect to the server.